# iPhone accessing one resource by two threads

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I want to synchronize one queue among two threads. Such as one thread performs enqueue and other performs dequeue. 
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa class like NSArray or NSMutableArray is non thread safe, you have to use object NSLock class to make them thread safe.